# Indefinite integral of a particular rational function

Tags: calculus, integration

I solved the following integral using the Hermite's decomposition method. 
I kindly ask you if there's a simpler way to solve this integral.

\begin{equation}
\int \frac{x-1}{(x^2+2x+3)^2} \, \mathrm{d} x = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \arctan \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}} +\frac{-x-2}{2(x^2+2x+3)} + K
\end{equation}

Solution: 
Using the Hemite's method, we can decompose the integrand function as
\begin{align*}
\frac{x-1}{(x^2+2x+3)^2} & = \frac{Bx+C}{x^2+2x+3} +\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} \left ( \frac{Dx+E}{x^2+2x+3} \right ) \\
& = \frac{Bx+C}{x^2+2x+3} + \frac{Dx^2+2Dx+3D-(2x+2)(Dx+E)}{(x^2+2x+3)^2} \\
& = \frac{Bx^3+x^2(2B+C-D)+x(3B+2C-2E)+3C-2E+3D}{(x^2+2x+3)^2} 
\end{align*}
whence

\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\begin{aligned}
B &=0  \\
C &= - \frac{1}{2} \\
\quad D & = - \frac{1}{2} \\
E & =-1
\end{aligned}
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation*}
then
\begin{equation}
 \frac{x-1}{(x^2+2x+3)^2}  = \frac{-1}{2(x^2+2x+3)} +\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} \left ( \frac{-x-2}{2(x^2+2x+3)} \right ).
\end{equation}
Integrating the previous equation we have
\begin{equation}\label{itegrHerm}
\int  \frac{x-1}{(x^2+2x+3)^2} \,  \mathrm{d} x = \int \frac{-1}{2(x^2+2x+3)} \, \mathrm{d} x+\frac{-x-2}{2(x^2+2x+3)} % \int \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} \left ( \frac{-x-2}  {2(x^2+2x+3)} \right )\,  \mathrm{d} x,
\end{equation}
thus, the integral in the right hand side of the last equation is solved as
\begin{equation}\label{int2}
\int \frac{-1}{2(x^2+2x+3)} \, \mathrm{d} x= -\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2+2} \, \mathrm{d} x= -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \arctan \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}} + K.
\end{equation}
Finally, the statement follows easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add and subtract something to make a substitution:
$$
\int \frac{x-1}{(x^2+2x+3)^2}+\frac{2}{(x^2+2x+3)^2}-\frac{2}{(x^2+2x+3)^2}\,dx
$$
$$
=\int \frac{x+1}{(x^2+2x+3)^2}\,dx-\int\frac{2}{(x^2+2x+3)^2}\,dx
$$The first integral can be evaluated using the substitution $z=x^2+2x+3$. For the second, complete the square in the denominator:
$$
-2\int\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+2}\,dx
$$Now you can use trig substitution, with $x+1=\sqrt{2}\tan(\theta)$:
$$
-2\int\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+2}\,dx\Rightarrow \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\int \cos^2(\theta)\,d\theta = \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int 1+\cos(2\theta)\,d\theta
$$
$$
=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)\right)+K=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\theta+\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\right)+K
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{2} (x+1)}{x^2+2x+3}\right)+K
$$Collecting terms gives the same result.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks.